# Что происходит в баш скрипте?

Tags: linux, bash

Не силен в bash, тем более в настолько замудренном)

```
if [ ${#d_p} -ge 3 ]
then
    ruble=`echo ${d_p:0:${#d_p}-2}`
    penny=`echo ${d_p:${#d_p}-2:${#d_p}}`
    d_r=$(($d_r+$ruble))
    d_p=$penny
else
    penny=`echo ${d_p:${#d_p}-2:${#d_p}}`
fi
```

В общем понятно, что происходит какая-то работа с переменными. Проверяем, что d_p больше или равно 3, но вот какие расчеты происходят внутри малопонятны. Пробовал подставлять какие-то числа в переменные, что бы посмотреть выхлоп и вопрос остался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот скрипт проверяет длину строки переменной `d_p`.

Если длина строки больше или равна 3, то скрипт разбивает строку на две части: `ruble` (рубли) и `penny` (копейки).

Затем скрипт добавляет рубли к переменной `d_r` и обновляет переменную `d_p` значением копеек.

Если длина строки меньше 3, то скрипт просто извлекает значение копеек в переменную `penny`.

Comment: Получается вот такая конструкций ${#d_p} это проверка длины переменной? И значит вот это конструкция echo ${d_p:0:${#d_p}-2} это обрезание строки с 0 символа до len(str) - 2?